# jQuery UI min script errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-ui

I get errors from [Eclipse v3.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Indigo) when using jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js. It seems that the script is working properly, and I do not get any errors from the browsers.

I created a custom jQuery UI theme and downloaded it from jQuery site, but I get three main errors when I put the script into a Maven project in Eclipse.

> Cannot return from outside a function or method 
> Syntax error on token "Invalid Regular Expression Options", no accurate correction available 
> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments

And dozens of `missing semicolon` warnings...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a problem? Does anything not work?

Comment: The script is working properly (it seems) but Eclipse indicates parsing errors on it which bugs me a lot, it is very distracting...

Comment: Disable the warnings if it's annoying you. Alternately use a different IDE.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, changing the IDE or disabling the warnings is not applicable, I am sure you will understand why.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349020). [Comment 15](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349020#c15) has a suggested workaround for getting the validator to ignore certain files, and it might be worth trying.

Comment: I see. I got rid of the errors by removing the script from the project and importing it from public hosts. Of course, this might be not the best solution since the app could be an intranet app, but luckily this is not the case.

Comment: I take it SO is a better source than Google. Works for me.

Answer (score 11):

You must ignore the specific project in the JavaScript validator.

Go: menu *Project* → *Properties* → *JavaScript* → *Include Path* → *Source*.

[Refer to the following](http://www.coderanch.com/t/554847/vc/JQuery-jquery-min-js-errors).

Answer (score 0):

For this type of error, you do not need to worry. You just need to bypass the validation error so you need to ignore the JavaScript Validator library in the source code.

Go: menu *Project* → *Properties* → *JavaScript* → *Include Path* → *Source => include.
Click on *include* and clean the project. Now your project will
be errorfree.